# Permission issues with default deployment script in Azure Web App (linux) dotnet core 2.2

Tags: git, azure, .net-core, nuget, azure-web-app-service

Using the local git deployment method in an Azure WebApp (linux) for dotnet core 2.2 I get permission issues with what I am guessing a default nuget path.

This being my deployment pipeline on bitbucket

```
- step:
  image: microsoft/dotnet
  name: Deploy DataCore
  script:
    - git subtree split -P data-core -b split
    - git push https://$BACKEND_LOGIN:$BACKEND_PASSWORD@$BACKEND_GITURL split:master --force
```

This is what is returned from remote and also part of the deployment logs:

```
+ git push https://$BACKEND_LOGIN:$BACKEND_PASSWORD@$BACKEND_GITURL split:master --force
remote: Deploy Async        
remote: Updating branch 'master'.        
remote: Updating submodules.        
remote: Preparing deployment for commit id '449e740796'.        
remote: Generating deployment script.        
remote: Running deployment command...        
remote: Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.        
remote: .........................
remote:   Restoring packages for /home/site/repository/data-core.csproj...        
remote: .
remote:   Installing NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0.        
remote: /opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/var/nuget/nuget.frameworks/4.7.0' is denied. [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]        
remote: /opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]        
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.        
remote: dotnet restore failed        
remote: App container will begin restart within 10 seconds.        
remote: Deployment Logs : 'https://_NAME_.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui/jsonviewer?view_url=/api/deployments/449e74079667b8ff046c75a45d4e2e251f99e4d0/log'        
To https://_NAME_.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/_NAME_.git
   9bfde94..449e740  split -> master
```

Note the two errors

```
remote:   Installing NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0.        
remote: /opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/var/nuget/nuget.frameworks/4.7.0' is denied. [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]        
remote: /opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]
```

This WebApp hasn't been configured outside the default and I have used this setup at other times. So I am wondering if there has been an update that requires me to change something.

This is my .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <RootNamespace>data_core</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Full deployment log here also

```
[{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:18.5348434Z","id":"","message":"Command: \"/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh\"","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:18.6366309Z","id":"","message":"Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:47.6970957Z","id":"","message":"  Restoring packages for /home/site/repository/data-core.csproj...","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.3146873Z","id":"","message":"  Installing NuGet.Frameworks 4.7.0.","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.3801758Z","id":"","message":"/opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Access to the path '/var/nuget/nuget.frameworks/4.7.0' is denied. [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.4164253Z","id":"","message":"/opt/dotnet/2.2.104/sdk/2.2.104/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Permission denied [/home/site/repository/data-core.csproj]","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.5778675Z","id":"","message":"An error has occurred during web site deployment.","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.6091768Z","id":"","message":"dotnet restore failed","type":0,"details_url":null},{"log_time":"2019-05-07T08:41:53.6748839Z","id":"","message":"\\n/opt/Kudu/KuduConsole/Scripts/starter.sh \"/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh\"","type":2,"details_url":null}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there were issues with this specific package. It attempts to write in the global NuGet folders, which obviously are write-protected.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.3" />
```

So I removed it

Comment: Did you remove the package to fix the issue, or did you upgrade versions to resolve the problem? Something else?